# anychart bubble map change data set

Tags: javascript, charts, html5-canvas, anychart

I want to change anychart bubble map data. when i change bubble dataset add new bubbles. but not remove old bubbles in map. How can I set new bubble dataset to the map. this is my code example. I want To replace with old bubbles to new bubbles data.

```js
/*-------------------------------------------------------*/
        var dataSet = anychart.data.set([
            {
                name: "Colombo",
                lat: 6.7768798,
                long: 79.9562153,
                'size': 10,
                desc: "We can even have VERY GOOD waves but the main problem is the very low frequency...."
            },
            {
                name: "Kandy",
                lat: 7.302461,
                long: 80.6409725,
                'size': 4,
                desc: "Kandy Sales Updated."
            }
            
        ]);
    var dataSet2 = anychart.data.set([
        {
            name: "devndara",
            lat: 8.277899131156953,
            long: 80.57335996768477,
            "size": 10,
            desc: "New Location Added"
        }
    ]);
/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 

function changebbl() {
    map.bubble(dataSet2);

}
```

```html
<div id="lkmapcontainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can do that, one is shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/prypezsk/

```
// create a data set    
var dataSet = anychart.data.set([
{'id': 'AU.NT', 'value': 15, 'size': 4},
]);

// prepare replacement data
var newData = [
{'id': 'AU.SA', 'value': 21, 'size': 15},
{'id': 'AU.VI', 'value': 5, 'size': 3},
{'id': 'AU.TS', 'value': 9, 'size': 1},
{'id': 'AU.WA', 'value': 23, 'size': 9},
];

// when needed - replace data in the data set
function changebbl() {
    dataSet.data(newData);
}
```

Comment: In my Case Im pointing bubbles by long, lat. So is it possible to apply this method.. Can You explain it by example.. Thank You